# /var/www/vhosts/sahinucar.com.tr/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1890

Tags: wordpress

My website is not working properly. I get this error:
/var/www/vhosts/xyz.com.tr/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1890
Following is the code on those lines. What is the problem in this code that it throws out an error?

```
        // Return number of rows affected
        $return_val = $this->rows_affected;
    } else {
        $num_rows = 0;
        if ( $this->use_mysqli && $this->result instanceof mysqli_result ) {
            **while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $this->result ) ) {
                $this->last_result[$num_rows] = $row;
                $num_rows++;**
            }
        } elseif ( is_resource( $this->result ) ) {
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $this->result ) ) {
                $this->last_result[$num_rows] = $row;
                $num_rows++;
            }
        } 

        // Log number of rows the query returned
        // and return number of rows selected
        $this->num_rows = $num_rows;
        $return_val     = $num_rows;
    }

    return $return_val;
}

/**
```

Comment: What was the error that got thrown?

Comment: Provide us with full error message.

Comment: **mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com.tr/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0**

I tried changing the memory to 64M/128M/256M on config.php but for no effect.